# PHP: How to serve customized content based on hundreds of user options?

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, logic, user-input

I'm working on a long, long user form which will then lead to a customized display.

The final display has to be curated, paragraph by paragraph, to fit the user's input.

My first attempt was all `if` statements:

```
if($input_a && $input_b && $input_c !== $input_d) :

   echo result;

   if($input_a === 'example') :

      return false;

   endif;

   if($input_b !== 'example') :

      echo $input_c * $input_d;

   endif;

endif;
```

This got very messy, especially when I had to pass the results of this logic between JS and PHP.

My next attempt involved building a custom string for each user, based on some of the inputs ('x' means no input):

```
$code = array('x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x');

if($input_a && $input_b && $input_c !== $input_d) :

   $code[0] = 1;
   $code[1] = 1;

   if($input_a === 'example') :

      $code[2] = 1;

   else:

      $code[2] = 0;

   endif;

   if($input_b !== 'example') :

      $code[3] = 1;

   else :

      $code[3] = 0

   endif;

else :

     $code[0] = 0;
     $code[1] = 0;

endif;
```

So, in the above, the string would read something like `'01x0'`. Now I can assign the user this code, based on their input. Further along in the logic, I can check against this code to decide whether to serve some blocks of content or hide others.

If I want to check for a match on the first and fourth inputs, but don't care about the second and third, I can do this:

```
// 'x' is a placeholder for code items I don't care about
$result_option = '1xx1';

$pattern = '/[' . $code[0] . 'x][' . $code[1] . 'x][' . $code[2] . 'x]/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $result_option) :

   echo $result_option;

endif;
```

Ok, so this works.

But I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here and eventually my code string is going to be a hundred characters long.

Are there better ways to serve customized content based on hundreds of user options that doesn't involve a hundred classes of nested `if` statements?

**Edit:**

So just to be clearer on what I'm trying to accomplish, let's say fills in the form. They say they own a house and a car and they have a lot of debt.

For that user, I want to show them content about dealing with debt, and that's it.

Another user fills in the form. They say they rent and they lease a car and they have moderate debt.

For that user, I want to show the same debt content, slightly modified because their debt is less extreme. In addition to that, I want to show content on buying a house and the benefits of buying a used car.

Each user has a unique combination of attributes, and for each attribute, custom content is served.

Comment: Use a Database, then you won't need to do checks - Soft coding is better than hard coding ;)

Comment: How do these hundreds of user options affect the rendering of the content? Can you give some concrete examples?

Comment: Basically, the user is served a post of text content. But paragraph by paragraph the text is customized based on their input. Some of the content is global — all users see it regardless of their input — but much of it is personalized.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Kyle - insert into a database and then create a class to handle the data manipulation that queries the new DB record(s).

In a simple example:

1. User enters all data on a form on a page
2. User submits form
3. On the subsequent page, the first thing you do is create a new record (or records) in a MySQL table and get the newly-created ID
   for the record(s)
4. Now you can have a class or set of classes to handle each data point or data set

I'm not super clear on your end objective, but I might use a template page that instantiates the above-referenced class and, for each data point I want to display, I call a function in that object to do the business logic.  It's not necessarily a better solution than just using the $_POST data directly, but for me such an approach helps me break down the task logically and in a clean, simplified fashion.
(NOTE: this should solve the nested 'if's but may not shorten your code per-se.)

UPDATE:
I actually do something similar to what you're talking about but with much less custom content and I use a .txt template file and then basically parse it.
The template (which is static):

```
<p>
Hi {recipientFname},<br>
{senderFname} has nominated you for membership into blah blah. As per your conversation with him, visit the site by following the below URL for your next steps.<br><br>
{choiceLines}
</p>
```

Then I have a class that does all the muscle work, but the important part is here:

```
    $arr_tpl_vars = array('{salutation}',
                        '{directMessage}',
                        '{referralMessage}',
                        '{senderFname}',
                        '{parentFname}',
                        '{parentLname}',
                        '{memberFname}',
                        '{memberLname}',
                        '{recipientFname}'
    );
    $arr_tpl_data = array($this->recipient_salutation, 
                        $directMessage, 
                        $referralMessage, 
                        $this->sender_fname, 
                        $this->parent_fname, 
                        $this->parent_lname, 
                        $this->memberFname, 
                        $this->memberLname, 
                        $recipFname);
    $msg = str_replace($arr_tpl_vars, $arr_tpl_data, $msg_tmpl);
```

With the above code, I basically load in the template, feed it the array of strings to look for (all the replaceable content is denoted by {string} ) and the function replaces everything.

In your case, I'd define the text to use (ex: $this->recipient) in business logic functions...

Comment: So the end result is customized text content. The user sees a page of text, but the text itself is personalized based on their input. Some might see text suggesting one course of action, others might see another. Since there are many variables, there are maybe 100 different possible instances of that text content.

Comment: I think working with a database makes a lot of sense, but I think I'm still missing how it helps the logic. Whether I'm pulling the data from $_POST or from the database, I still have to curate the final content based on each data point.

Comment: See update to answer above - I think it may answer what you need, DB or no DB.